# Parallel threads in PHP

Tags: php, parallel-processing

I have a virtual machine hosted on Windows Azure and have set up a LAMP stack on it. The website allows users to create albums and upload images. These images are stored in Windows azure blob storage. As images can be big, i split the file into chunks and then upload them as follows:

```
$blockMaxSize = 2*1024*1024; //2MB
            $fileSize = $_FILES['Filedata']['size'];
            $numOfBlocks = $fileSize/$blockMaxSize;
            $currentFileIndex = 0;
            $blockId=1;
            $blocklist = new BlockList();
            while($numOfBlocks>0)
            {
                $content = file_get_contents($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'],NULL,NULL,$currentFileIndex,$blockMaxSize);
                $currentFileIndex+=$blockMaxSize;
                $numOfBlocks-=1; //Read the current block.

                //upload the block
                $blobRestProxy->createBlobBlock(Actual_Image, $blobName, md5($blockId),$content);
                $blocklist->addLatestEntry(md5($blockId));
                $blockId++;
            }

            $blobRestProxy->commitBlobBlocks(Actual_Image, $blobName, $blocklist->getEntries());
```

This can take a lot of time for a file which is greater than 5Mb or so. I was looking at way or performing parallel uploads to the blob storage to make the uploading faster. I was looking at creating a *$content* array which contains the file data and then uploading those contents in parallel. I read up on *exec* and *pcntl_fork* but fork is disabled on the server and I am not sure if I can use exec for this as that executes a command.

Is it possible to do this in PHP? Maybe using [POSIX](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.posix.php) threads.

Not sure if this information is needed but the virtual machine had 4 cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has no built-in support for multithreading.

You can use an approach like the one posted by John Lim though:

http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/?q=node/view/254

Not very robust, but it should afford you a bit of multitasking.

See this code there

```
if (1) {  /* SAMPLE USAGE BELOW */

$fp1 = JobStartAsync('localhost','/jobs/j1.php');
$fp2 = JobStartAsync('localhost','/jobs/j2.php');


while (true) {
    sleep(1);

    $r1 = JobPollAsync($fp1);
    $r2 = JobPollAsync($fp2);

    if ($r1 === false && $r2 === false) break;

    echo "<b>r1 = </b>$r1<br>";
    echo "<b>r2 = </b>$r2<hr>";
    flush(); @ob_flush();
}

echo "<h3>Jobs Complete</h3>";
}
```

You can add your files like this for parallal processing.

Comment: this looks good but is there a way for me to pass arguments to these files? I would need to pass the contents and Id information to them so that they have the data to upload.

Comment: You can always pass data as query string.